# Not able to install the Perl module Device::USB on Windows

Tags: perl

I need to run a perl program on Windows. I install Strawberry Perl.
I am not able to install Device::USB module.
Here is the revelant error in log :

```
-> OK
Successfully installed Inline-0.80
Installing C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\lib\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\.meta\Inline-0.80\install.json
Installing C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\lib\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\.meta\Inline-0.80\MYMETA.json
Configuring Device-USB-0.36
Running Makefile.PL
ERROR: Missing required environment variables to compile under Windows.

    LIBUSB_LIBDIR should contain the path to the libusb libraries
    LIBUSB_INCDIR should contain the path to the libusb include files

-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed f
```

Comment: [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/).

Answer (score 1):

As the error msg states, you should define the two environment variables `LIBUSB_LIBDIR` and `LIBUSB_INCDIR`.
Under windows on the command line you can add env vars (temporarily, for the currend cmd process) via `SET name=value`, e.g.: `SET LIBUSB_LIBDIR=C:\your\path\to\the\libs`.

Also, libusb has to be installed on your machine - maybe this also will set the lib&include path env vars permanently. (thx for comment! :)

Comment: It's probalby also required to install a Windows version of libusb first.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the *libusb* library on your system.

> Device-USB
>
> This module provides a relatively complete Perl wrapper on the libusb
>   library. Using this module provides an object-oriented interface to any 
>   installed USB devices.
>
> Obviously, the module requires a copy of the libusb library compiled for the
>   target system. The module also requires a C compiler compatible with the
>   Perl installation, because it uses the Inline::C module to create the 
>   interface to libusb.

Then, you need to tell Device::USB where to locate the library by setting env var `LIBUSB_LIBDIR` to the directory that contains the libusb DLL, and by setting env var `LIBUSB_INCDIR` to the directory that contains the libusb `.h` files.

You can set those env vars by right-clicking "My Computer", clicking "Properties", clicking "Advanced system settings", clicking "Environment Variables".